# JBoss Mysql Increasing Connections

Tags: java, mysql, sockets, jboss

We have an application which we run inside the JBoss EJB Container. This application makes connections to mysql and runs stored procedures on mysql. We have observed that after a point in time Jboss stops responding to web connections to web application hosted on it. So after investigating we have found the following issues.

1. The number of socket connections from jboss keeps on increasing and once it goes above thousand we observe that jboss stops working completely because of the limit on a process for the number of socket connections(i.e 1024), we have cross checked the code for socket connections, but we feel it makes socket connections only to mysql, so either this is a problem or something else is doing this, can't find the actual cause. We have tried using netstat, lsof on linux, any other suggestions to finding the root cause of the connection issue would be of great help.
2. We also checked the show processlist of mysql, but it shows only 8 to 10 active connections at any point in time. So no luck here.
3. There is also another interesting thing, we had reduced the timeout for connections from our application from 86400 seconds to 30 seconds, and we have reduced the wait timeout for mysql database to 50 seconds, so there is a gap of 20 seconds. We have again and again cross checked the database for any issues with this, but this hardly affects it. But any suggestions in this would also be helpful. We plan to reduce the difference to 5 seconds.

**Update :** We have subsequently changed the connection timeout from 30 to 170 and also mysql waittimeout to 180

we have tried making changes according to jboss forums where it says cache connection manager tag, we have to enable an attribute called debug=true, we have tried this solution, but what happens is if there are transactions, this causes them to drop off, which is causing havoc in our application, we subsequently reverted the changes, and are running it just like that, but the application is still on the verge of a disaster. We are still running clueless, JBOSS seems to be at the core of our issues, still no solution :(

Comment: Are you using a connection pool? I suffered from a connection leak a while ago and your symptoms are very close.

Comment: Yes we are using the managed connection pool. We have cross checked the connection logic like hundred times, but still not getting why this is happening.